# frame blocked with origin error when using google.load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-api, umbraco

I am working on a project that uses the google visualisation package in an ASP.net website that uses the Umbraco cms.

I am using this in conjunction with the analytics API to report on users own analytics.

due to the way that the scripts are loaded i found that the only way to get the google.load function to work properly was to wrap it in a setTimeout function like so:

```
setTimeout(function () {

        google.load('visualization', '1', {
            'callback': handleClientLoad, 'packages': ['corechart']
        })
    }, 500);
```

This works a treat, but when i load it up in Chrome i get this error:

Blocked a frame with origin "http://local-webcast.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

I was wondering if anyone has a way around this?

I am not 100% sure if it is this that is causing it, or the iframe which loads the login for the analytics

the scripts i load are:

thanks in advance for any help

EDIT:

i thought i solved it but it appears to be deeper than i thought.

on my webserver i have a virtual directory in IIS which points to my main Umbraco folder, this gives me local-webcast.com/admin and local-webcast.com/umbraco as the admin is a virtual directory it is exactly the same as the umbraco folder. when i visit this page on /admin i do not get the errors, when i visit on /umbraco i do.....

confused massively

Comment: It's the [`Same-origin policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), like your error message says, `Protocols must match.`